# Data change notification in Silverlight listbox with databinding to WCF Service

Tags: wcf, silverlight, data-binding

I have inherited some Silverlight\WCF code and now need to implement some new features.  I fairly new to Silverlight\WCF so my question may be rather basic. So...

I have a listbox in Silverlight that binds to a resource that is a List<> returned from a WCF (rest) service (which is just reading values from a db table).  I have implemented the ability to add new items to the db table through a WCF service and now want to make my listbox update once it has been added to the db.

It is possible that my initial code needs to change so I have listed the relevant lines below.

In xaml the resource is as such:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="myWCFSvc">
  <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    <scm:SortDescription Direction="Ascending" PropertyName="ID" />
  </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

And the binding of the listbox is:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myWCFSvc}}
```

And the .cs has in the callback

```
((CollectionViewSource)LayoutRoot.Resources["WCFSvc"]).Source = myList;
```

So now if a user adds a new entry through another Silverlight childwindow an new entry is created in the db and I want to update the listbox to include this entry.  I'm unclear how to do this.

I know there are observablecollections and INotifyPropertyChanged but unsure if this is those are what I need, or how to use them in this context.  I searched around a bit but the examples I found don't seem fit my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original thoughts are correct, the type you are looking for is the `ObservableCollection<T>`.

If you replace your existing `List` with this then as changes are made to its membership by other code it will notify other interested parties such as the `CollectionViewSource`, which in turn will notify anyting that is binding to it.